# $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$-equivariant maps on $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, equivariant, modular-group

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Can you describe the maps from $\GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ to $\GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ that are equivariant w.r.t. right multiplication by $\GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$? I'm interested even in classes of examples, not necessarily a full description.

Of course, there are maps that are equivariant to the whole $\GL(n, \mathbb{R})$. What else is there?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The ones equivariant by all of GL(n,R) are the left multiplications. For what you like, writing $f(g)=s(g)g$, we see that $s(g)=s(gh)$ for all $h\in$GL(n,Z). Hence, the answer is the maps $f(g)=s(g)g$ for such maps $s$ (i.e., factoring through maps GL(n,R)/GL(n,Z)$\to$ GL(n,R). If you require the map to be continuous, this means that $s$ is continuous.

Comment: What kind of description would satisfy you? If $n=1$, you are talking about all odd functions $\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$.